# Python list comparison generates Infinite Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, linked-list, infinite-loop

So the assignment is: 
take 2 lists and write a program that returns a list that contains only the elements that are common to the lists without duplicates, and it must work on lists of different sizes.

My code is:

```
a = [1, 2, 4]
b = [3, 1, 5, 2]

for j < len(a):
    for i < len(b):
        if a(elem) == b(i):
            print (a(elem))
        i=i+1
    j=j+1
```

An infinite loop is then generated, where it prints 1 and then never exits.

Can someone tell me why the infinite loop occurs?

I understand this is not the most "python" way of doing things, however my coding background includes a very small, brute force technique of C, and I do not know much Python.

If there are simple alternatives to this, please let me know, as well as why it never exits.

Comment: I don't see a list comprehension here. And this runs? `for j < len(a):` doesn't look like valid syntax.

Comment: This is completely invalid Python syntax, how are you executing this script?

Comment: anwayway the solution is `list(set(a).intersection(b))`

Comment: Also, neither `a` nor `b` is callable, so that code shouldn't even *run*, let alone go into an infinite loop.

Comment: @Carcigenicate they said list comparison, but yep, voting to close unless question is edited

Comment: @Chris_Rands Oh dur, I read that as "list comprehension" in the title. Oh the irony of misreading "comprehension".

Comment: This code must be outright failing with errors, but you're not seeing the errors and are assuming an infinite loop. Always looks for errors when in doubt, although rarely are they ever hidden.

Comment: @Carcigenicate awkward. i just made a list comprehension solution because thats what i thought it said too haha

Comment: PyCharm ran it and spat out infinite 1s. Sorry for the list comprehension confusion!

Comment: @KatCoder did you try either of the solutions in the answer i provided? I think both handle your problem just fine.

Comment: @GrantWilliams Yes I did. Sorry I wasn't able to update it sooner. Thanks again! I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use list comprehension use something like this

```
[i for i in a if i in b]
```

which outputs

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 4]
>>> b = [3, 1, 5, 2]
>>> [i for i in a if i in b]
[1, 2]

>>> b = [1, 2, 4]
>>> a = [3, 1, 5, 2]
>>> [i for i in a if i in b]
[1, 2]
```

Or use @Chris_Rand's Clean set solution:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 4]
>>> b = [3, 1, 5, 2]
>>> list(set(a).intersection(b))
[1, 2]
```

Since i originally thought the title said list comprehension i gave you a list comprehension answer. You should absolutely use Chris's set solution though.

Here is a (non statistically significant) benchmark showing why

```
>>> a = list(np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=500))
>>> b = list(np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=800))

>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='[i for i in a if i in b]', globals=globals(), number=1000)
9.176704404999327

>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='list(set(a).intersection(b))', globals=globals(), number=1000)
0.05484662300295895
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make something like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 4]
b = [3, 1, 5, 2]
j=0
while j < len(a):
print("J:", j)
i = 0
while i < len(b):
    print("I:", i)
    if j == i:
        print ("match :", a[j], b[i])
    i=i+1
j=j+1
```

or with for (and more pretty):

```
a = [1, 2, 4]
b = [3, 1, 5, 2]

for j in a:
    print("J:", j)
    for i in b:
        print("I:", i)
        if j == i:
            print ("match :", a[j], b[i])
```

This will be display the indices where the values are equal.